# не работает плавный прыжок в Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, unity3d-editor

```
void Update()
    {
        float moveX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + Vector2.right * moveX * speed * Time.deltaTime); 

        if (grounded && (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)))
            //rb.AddForce(transform.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse); // резко
            //rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpForce)); --> не работает
            //rb.AddForce(Vector2.up*8000*Time.deltaTime); //--> не работает с Time.deltaTime
```

Нашел в интернете 3 варианта, попробовал все, но прыжок все равно резкий (будто телепорт). Видел совет умножать на Time.deltaTime, но тогда персонаж вообще прыгать отказывается... Подскажите, как прыжок плавным сделать?

Answer (score 1):

```
var jumpVectorAndPowerOfJump = new Vector2(0, 10);
rigidbody2D.AddForce(jumpVectorAndPowerOfJump , ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

или

```
gameObj.rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector3.up * 10 * Time.deltaTime);
//направление * на множитель силы прыжка * на промежуток времени пере просчетом следующей силы на прорисовке следующего кадра
```